# how to write a trriger for this scenario

Tags: apex, trigger

Here we have two types of passengers, one is Lead Passenger and other is Guest Passenger. Lead Passenger is the responsible person for Guest Passengers. For example, if you are travelling with your family, you will be the Lead passenger and your family members will be Guest Passengers. Lead Passenge may have 1 to 5 Guest Passengers. 
(lead passenger is standard contact object and guest in custom object)

I want show error message when lead passenger add more than 5 guest passenger

Comment: what is your exact requirement? what values you need to create/update/delete ?

Comment: What did you try so far?

Comment: What have you got so far? What should the trigger executed on? What should the trigger do?

Comment: I want show error message when lead passenger add more than 5 guest passenger

Comment: Roll up summary field with validation rule should do nicely

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of All, create the Custom Object ‘**Guest__c**’ and create Custom field ‘**Lead__c**’ with the lookup of Contact(Lead).

**Apex Class**

```
public Class LeadPassengerTrgrHandler
    {
        public static void method(list<Guest__c> guestList)
        {
            list<Id> IdsForGuest=new list<Id>();
            for(Guest__c g:guestList)
            {
                IdsForGuest.add(g.Lead__c);
            }
            list<Guest__c> allGuests=[select id,Lead__c from Guest__c where Lead__c IN : IdsForGuest];
            map<Id,list<Guest__c>> listOfGuestWithLeadId=new map<Id,list<Guest__c>>();
            for(Guest__c g:allGuests)
            {
                if(listOfGuestWithLeadId.get(g.Lead__c)==NULL)
                {
                    listOfGuestWithLeadId.put(g.Lead__c , new list<Guest__c>());
                }
                listOfGuestWithLeadId.get(g.Lead__c).add(g); 
            }
            for(Guest__c gs:guestList)
            {
                list<Guest__C> gList=listOfGuestWithLeadId.get(gs.Lead__c);
                if(gList.size()>5)
                {
                    gs.addError('Lead Passenger can not add more tha 5 guest passenger.');
                }
            }

        }
    }
```

**Apex Trigger**

```
trigger LeadPassengerValidation on Guest__c (after insert,after Update) {
LeadPassengerTrgrHandler.method(Trigger.new);
}
```

Comment: Thanks Rahul for selecting my answer as a best answer .It's my pleasure to help you!